# After updating my packages, two packages are not working anymore. How to solve this? Downgrading it? Bug reporting to maintainers? Fixing?

Tags: package, use-package, package-repositories, upgrade, automation

This is my [config](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el) file. As you can see, on [line 351](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/0615157d9f838160c61b090fe0a3da97846abf19/.emacs.d/init.el#L351), there is:

```lisp
;; Update my Emacs' packages every week
(use-package auto-package-update
    :custom
    (auto-package-update-interval 7)
    (auto-package-update-prompt-before-update t)
    (auto-package-update-hide-results t)
    :config
    (auto-package-update-maybe)
    (auto-package-update-at-time "09:00"))
```

After starting Emacs, the mini-buffer asked me about updating the packages earlier today. I chose "yes".

Usually, things are updated and work fine. However, this was not the case today.

After everything was processed, Emacs indicated the upgrade process went fine. So, I decided to re-start Emacs. And now Emacs was loading with the following error messages:

```lisp
Error (use-package): doom-modeline/:init: Symbol’s function definition is void: compat--inhibit-prefixed
Error (use-package): doom-modeline/:catch: Symbol’s function definition is void: compat--inhibit-prefixed
```

Indeed, the `modeline` was not working. After a bit, I realized that doom-mode was not the only problem.

When I try to use Magit via command `magit-status`, I get:

```lisp
byte-code: Symbol’s function definition is void: compat--inhibit-prefixed
```

I managed to solve the error message related to the `doom-modeline` by simply commenting the lines on my config "use-packaging" it:

```lisp
;; (use-package doom-modeline
;;   :init (doom-modeline-mode 1)
;;   :custom ((doom-modeline-height 15)))
```

The error message was out when starting Emacs. But, for obvious reason, it is still not working after being commented out. I can live without this package.

The magit problem persists. And this is really annoying because I can't live without this package.

How should I proceed?

Any suggestion on how to debug the problem?

Is there a way to downgrade the last changes generated by [auto-package-update](https://github.com/rranelli/auto-package-update.el)?

Any clue on how to solve things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
byte-code: Symbol’s function definition is void: compat--inhibit-prefixed
```

If this is the error, then running `M-x pacakge-recompile compat RET` (if you are on Emacs 29) or `M-x package-reinstall compat RET`.  Fundamentally the issue appears to be that some files were not compiled in the correct order, and the macro [`compat--inhibit-prefixed`](https://git.sr.ht/%7Epkal/compat/tree/aaf21398355d9d2abee33fe5a620792ea8ad9315/item/compat-macs.el#L38) was not recognized as such in [some other file](https://git.sr.ht/%7Epkal/compat/tree/aaf21398355d9d2abee33fe5a620792ea8ad9315/item/compat-28.el#L878).

(Also a friendly reminder to report issues like these to their respective [issue trackers](https://todo.sr.ht/%7Epkal/compat). That way the package author is directly notified and can investigate the issue more efficiently.  Use `C-h P` to find out what who maintains a package/what dependencies there are, and `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` or invoke Emacs with `--debug-init` to create a backtrace.)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try re-compiling everything, all packages.

Thus, I typed `M-:` to eval an expression and then inserted: `(byte-recompile-directory package-user-dir nil 'force)`.

After re-starting Emacs, both packages are working fine again.

This old question from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725778/how-to-rebuild-elpa-packages-after-upgrade-of-emacs) helped me out.

Comment: This is undoubtedly the best first step (and if you are lucky, the *only* step) to get things working again.